# axe devtools highlights aria-expanded error on accordion

Tags: accessibility

I am running Axe DevTools on chrome browser for accessibility on the div which basically is an accordion using data-toggle.

DevTools highlighted the issue on the accordion header and panel content when expanded saying

'To solve this problem, you need to fix the following:
ARIA attribute is not allowed: aria-expanded="true"'

Div when closed (issue on the header saying ARIA attribute is not allowed: aria-expanded="false")

```
<div id="ctl00_panelAdditionalInfo" class="panel-group help-container">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel_content" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">Additional Information</div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="panel_content" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body help-content">   
                    <a class="additional-info" href="htpps://url" alt="alt" target="_blank"><u>text</u></a>
                    <a class="additional-info" href="htpps://url" alt="alt" target="_blank"><u>text</u></a>
                    <a class="additional-info" href="htpps://url" alt="alt" target="_blank"><u>text</u></a>
                    <a class="additional-info" href="htpps://url" alt="alt" target="_blank"><u>text</u></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Div when expanded (issue on the header and panel content)

```
<div id="ctl00_panelAdditionalInfo" class="panel-group help-container">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel_content" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="true">Additional Information</div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="panel_content" aria-expanded="true">
                <div class="panel-body help-content">   
                    <a class="additional-info" href="htpps://url" alt="alt" target="_blank"><u>text</u></a>
                    <a class="additional-info" href="htpps://url" alt="alt" target="_blank"><u>text</u></a>
                    <a class="additional-info" href="htpps://url" alt="alt" target="_blank"><u>text</u></a>
                    <a class="additional-info" href="htpps://url" alt="alt" target="_blank"><u>text</u></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did review on the stackoverflow and seen few suggestions adding a role with button for header. But what role to use for panel content on expansion?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add aria-expanded on any HTML elements.

1. The HTML element need a correct role: [Aria-expanded can be used on roles](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-expanded)
2. Replace your DIV by a button: the button has a role which allows the aria-expanded attribute
3. Go check the pattern to build accessible accordion: [Accordeon pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/accordion/examples/accordion/)